# Create new columns from categorical variables

Tags: pandas, dataframe

| ID | column_factors | column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | fact1 | d | w |
| 1 | fact1, fact2 | a | x |
| 2 | fact3 | b | y |
| 3 | fact1,fact4 | c | z |

I have a table in pandas dataframe. What I would like create is, removing column "column_factors" and create new columns called "fact1", "fact2", "fact3", "fact4". And filling the new columns with dummy values as shown below. Thanks in advance,

| ID | fact1 | fact2 | fact3 | fact4 | column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | d | w |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | a | x |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | b | y |
| 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | c | z |

Comment: Are these strings or lists in column_factors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Series.str.get_dummies`

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html#pandas.Series.str.get_dummies

```
dummy_cols =  df['column_factors'].str.get_dummies(sep=',')
df = df.join(dummy_cols).drop(columns='column_factors')
```